# Why does the standard error of the intercept change when we shift the axis, say by centering?

Tags: r, regression, regression-coefficients, lm, centering

I was trying to understand how the calculations are done behind `lm()` function in R using `mtcars` dataset. I understand that `lm()` function minimizes the sum of the squared residuals to get the best fit line. Now the `summary()` done on that fit gives coefficient which includes: the intercept, slope, standard error, t-statistic, and P-value.

Suppose I fit a regression line with the `mtcars` dataset using 2 different approaches:

- when I don't shift the `x=wt` axis

  ```
  library(ggplot2)
  g <- ggplot(data=mtcars, aes(x=wt,y=mpg))
  g <- g+geom_point(size=2, color="blue", alpha=0.4)
  g <- g+geom_smooth(method = "lm")
  g <- g+ggtitle("Normal")
  g <- g+labs(x ="wt", y = "mpg")
  g
  ```

  [image]
- when I center the `x=wt` axis first:

  ```
  library(ggplot2)
  g <- ggplot(data=mtcars, aes(x=c(wt-mean(wt)), y=mpg))
  g <- g+geom_point(size=2, color="red", alpha=0.4)
  g <- g+geom_smooth(method="lm")
  g <- g+ggtitle("Shifted")
  g <- g+labs(x="wt", y="mpg")
  g
  ```

  [image]

So it is evident from the plots that the:

- Slopes are same (I understand that)
- intercepts change due to shifting of x-axis (I understand that)
- But the intercept's standard error in `summary(fit)` changes (I don't understand this)

Does it mean, the standard error outputted by the `summary()` function is the standard error in the response only at that x-value? and that this standard deviation will be different at different predictor values?

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KW]

[image]

Comment: I think you will find the information you need in the linked thread. Please 
read it. If it isn't what you want / you still have a question afterwards, 
come back here & edit your question to state what you learned & what you still 
need to know. Then we can provide the information you need without just 
duplicating material elsewhere that already didn't help you.

Comment: Thank you gung. It clears all my doubt now. Much appreciated.

Comment: You're welcome, @PiyushVerma. +1, although this is a duplicate, it is a good & clear question.